# Pivot item headers like instagram in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, azure, windows-phone-8

I need your ideas how can i put Segoe UI Font or icons to `Pivot` Headers. 
I started a new project and put basic `Pivot` on my XAML, if you ask more and more code, that's all.

This is the app link that i want to know how can they put items as icons rather than texts.
http://instagram.com/

i need sample code rather than fairy tale or success stories.

```
        <phone:PivotItem CacheMode="{x:Null}"   FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol" Header="feed"  >
```

Comment: I have tried putting the `&#xe158;` in to pivotitem name and directly changed the font family to segoe ui symbol, but it shows rectangular symbol.

Comment: Show it in your question so a reader trying to help has something to start with. Like for instance how you're specifying the FontFamily so if for example you're trying to do `FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol"` instead of just `FontFamily="Symbol"` or if it might not be a better idea to use [Symbol Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.symbol.aspx) instead of unicode.

Comment: this is what i have done and not working how can i put ?                <phone:PivotItem CacheMode="{x:Null}"   FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol" Header="#&xe136; feed"  >

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out there is a [great article](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Tabbed_interface_with_Pivot_animation_for_Windows_Phone) on the Nokia Developer Wiki for doing just that.

The gist of it is to not have a Header set for the PivotItem and instead to display a ListBox at the top of the page. You then link the ListBox SelectedIndex to the Pivot SelectedIndex.

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ListBox SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex, ElementName=ContentPivot, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <!-- Items -->
    </ListBox>
    <phone:Pivot x:Name="ContentPivot">
        <!-- Items -->
    </phone:Pivot>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

[This is the actual answer](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/1baf74fa-0ddd-4226-a02d-a7fc9f80374d/pivot-static-header-like-twitter-app) in MSDN forums.

..and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfpxX.png) is how it looks on the phone's screen.

Simply use the event handlers. **Tap** of Image and **SelectionChanged** of Pivot.

Here is the xaml I used:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="#2b5a83">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="82" 
          Background="#2b5a83" Canvas.ZIndex="1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Image x:Name="icon0" Grid.Column="0" 
               Source="/Assets/ApplicationIcon.png" 
               Opacity="0.5" Tap="icon0_Tap"/>
        <Image x:Name="icon1" Grid.Column="1" 
               Source="/Assets/ApplicationIcon.png" 
               Opacity="0.5" Tap="icon1_Tap" />
    </Grid>

    <!--Pivot Control-->
    <phone:Pivot Grid.Row="1" x:Name="MainPivot" 
                 Foreground="White" Background="#2b5a83" 
                 SelectionChanged="Pivot_SelectionChanged">

        <!--Pivot item one-->
        <phone:PivotItem>
            <TextBlock>
                Deneme
            </TextBlock>
        </phone:PivotItem>

        <!--Pivot item two-->
        <phone:PivotItem>
            <TextBlock>
                Deneme 2
            </TextBlock>
        </phone:PivotItem>
    </phone:Pivot>
</Grid>
```

... and the CSharp code-behind as follows:

```
    private void Pivot_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (MainPivot.SelectedIndex)
        {
            case 0:
                Select0();
                break;
            case 1:
                Select1();
                break;
            default:
                MessageBox.Show("Add another case and write it's new method, " + Environment.NewLine +
                    "Also bind the `Tap` event of another image to a new handler calling this newly created method.");
                break;
        }
    }

    private void Icon1_Tap(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        Select1();
    }

    private void Select0()
    {
        icon0.Opacity = 1.0;
        icon1.Opacity = 0.5;
        MainPivot.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }

    private void Select1()
    {
        icon1.Opacity = 1.0;
        icon0.Opacity = 0.5;
        MainPivot.SelectedIndex = 1;
    }

    private void icon0_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        Select0();
    }

    private void icon1_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        Select1();
    }
```

Try it! =) ...and let me know of the outcome:)